# A Proper Explanation for the following lex/yacc example

Tags: ubuntu, compiler-construction, ubuntu-14.04, yacc, lex

I am having difficulty understanding the following code.If possible suggest me a site where I can read through documentations or explain the code please with every detail.

```
%{
int yylineno;
%}
%%
^(.*)\n    printf("%4d\t%s", ++yylineno, yytext);
%%
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
yylex();
fclose(yyin);
}
```

Comment: What do you make of it so far?

Answer (score 0):

The code you've posted is lex (or flex) code. It is a specification for a lexical analyser that the lex (or similar flex) program will generate. These days, flex is more widely used than lex although I believe they're pretty much compatible with each other.

The official [flex documentation](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/) is very good. Here's [a link to a page](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Simple-Examples.html) in the manual where some simple examples like the one you've given are explained.

Hope this helps.